# Wireless not working on Lenovo G50-45

Tags: wifi, battery

Primeramente los felicito en la realización de gran SO. He instalado en una portátil (laptop) lenovo G50-45 de un amigo, y tengo problema con el wireless, conecto el wiffi y dura como máximo 15 minutos, y se cae la señal. Tengo que reiniciar el portátil para que se vuelva a conectar y vuelve dura el tiempo y se cae...quisiera que me ayudaran a arreglarl.

#### English Translation:

I don't primarily speak English, I'm using a translator. I really like the operating system. I installed the operating system on a laptop from a friend, and I have problems with the wi-fi. I connect to the network, and connected, but after 15 minutes it falls, and does not connect anymore. I have to restart the laptop and the problem recurs. I also see that the battery lasts for 62.5% (4 hours 100%). The laptop is a lenovo G50-45. I appreciate your attention and your cooperation, thank you very much.

Comment: English please =)

Answer (score 1):

Please open the terminal and enter this:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Drop the results on http://pastebin.com and link it here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with certain Atheros wifi adapters, affecting many models, including the Lenovo G50.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940

Answer (score 0):

First please run the following script ([taken from Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108)) in terminal:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info
```

This will create a file called `wireless-info.txt`, please paste the infos in [hastebin](http://hastebin.com/) or similar and link it in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with disconnection, I would solve it by changing the DNS and placing the google ones by editing the resolv.conf file with the following command

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

once inside, they change the "nameserver" and place 8.8.8.8 below another line that says the same but with 8.8.4.4

It would look like this

```
Nameserver 8.8.8.8
Nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

---

Si tienen problemas con desconeccion yo lo solucione cambiando la DNS y colocando las de google editando el archivo resolv.conf con el siguiente comando

```
sudo nano/etc/resolv.conf
```

una vez dentro, cambian el "nameserver" y colocan 8.8.8.8
abajo otra linea que diga lo mismo pero con 8.8.4.4

Quedaria asi

```
Nameserver 8.8.8.8
Nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

No se si les sirva, tengo pereza de escribirlo en ingles haha (Use Google Transator) Saludos :)

Answer (score -1):

`sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop`

Give that a shot.